# strongloop pm node does not start on fail

Tags: node.js, strongloop

We have installed node & strongloop on the server. We have also installed 
strong-pm. But we are not able to graceful restart. If node goes down it does not restart automatically by strong pm. Is there any log file generated where I can see the error.

command we run to install strongloop is as follow.

```
yum install nodejs npm
npm install -g strongloop
slc loopback
npm install
slc pm-install --upstart 0.6
/sbin/initctl start strong-pm
slc arc&
```

Answer (score 1):

In this configuration strong-pm's logs will be directed to syslog, so they will show up somewhere like `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: I installed strong-pm and started as services. I am able to graceful restart node when we make change in the code using cli  slc ctl cluster-restart servicename. But from arc cluster restart does not work. We need to stop nodejs controller and restart to get the new changes.

Comment: Code changes are not automatically redeployed to the running PM instance. You would need to rebuild and redeploy the application.